# Windows 7 Folder Redirection Failing for One User

Tags: windows-server-2012, folder-redirection

We're running a Windows Server 2012 Essentials & Windows 7 environment. I just setup folder redirection and it worked fine for all users except for one. In fact, all folders moved on this user except for the My Documents. The error stated the My Documents folder was corrupt and unreadable (error below). If I look on the server I see that all folders in My Docs were copied over, but not all files.

My question is two part: 1) Is there a way to tell which file(s) is corrupt and causing problems; and 2) how can I attempt to move them again considering some already moved and we have many other users already moved over?

**Error Message:**

Log: Application
Type: Error
Event: 502
Alert Time: 2013-04-28 17:23:43Z
Event Time: 09:21:51 PM 28-Apr-2013 UTC
Source: Microsoft-Windows-Folder Redirection
Category: None
Username: diane
Computer: SP-STATION-3.ourdomain.local
Description: Failed to apply policy and redirect folder "Documents" to "\SP-SERVER\Folder
Redirection\diane\Documents". Redirection options=0x1031.
 The following error occurred: "Failed to copy files from "C:\Users\Diane\Documents" to "\SP-SERVER\Folder Redirection\diane\Documents"".
Error details: "The file or directory is corrupted and unreadable.".

Answer (score 1):

I'd be looking at long folders / file names rather than corruption as such. You may try resetting permissions, too.

Alternatively, back up her My Docs. Delete the files, check redirection works and manually copy to the redirected folder. These steps may also highlight the original issue.

Comment: Good idea, Dan - thanks. There are thousands of files in here under many folders... any easy way to find long file names other than a PowerShell script?

Comment: Long file/folder names are the culprit most of the time with this problem.  Some users will name their files "File that I use to record debit entries for the system of accounting that I use to keep track of things that I want to keep track of and that the company requires that I keep track of."  The problem is that your root directory is longer than the old one.  You always want to try to make your share name shorter than c:\Users\User\Documents.

Comment: Ok, still not sure what the problem was, but we're good now. I took Dan's advice and removed everything from My Docs. The redirection worked fine, and then I manually copied directories and folders back in. Working great with no problems.